expl3 expansion error when using pdflatex
Looking for an answer to this question I got with pdflatex an error related to the expansion of \$ with expl3. For example :
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\mystring}{Special: Five (5) bananas for \$1.50.}

\test{\mystring}

\end{document}

raises
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\font@name ->
             \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 
l.15 \test{\mystring}
                            
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

The code compile without error with lualatex or xelatex, or if \$ is removed.
Why?

This is an illustrative example that life would be simpler if we used exclusively Unicode engines and did not support non-Unicode. Then this problem would not exist at all.

@wipet for \$ yes but it's always possible to come up with some command that isn't safe in edef or expanded and you need to either not use edef or use a \protected definition for the content. The issue never completely goes.

You are using the default OT1 encoding in which \$ is not safe in an expansion context such as an e argument as it has to set up new fonts to switch between £ and $ which share the same position in OT1.
Either don't use the e argument or define your \mystring to be \protected so that it does not expand in e arguments, or use an encoding in which \$ is safe in an expansion context.
So one of these choices:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystring}{Special: Five (5) bananas for \$1.50.}

\test{\mystring}

\end{document}

or
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\mystring {} {Special: Five (5) bananas for \$1.50.}

\test{\mystring}

\end{document}

or
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystring}{Special: Five (5) bananas for \$1.50.}

\test{\mystring}

\end{document}

